# C# Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string literals

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2015

When I add a static string property to my class that returns a long string I get this error.

In the same project I have added lots of string properties over 20k chars, but when I create another property returning a string and build the project I get this error.

How can I increase that limit? I tried to use Stringbuilder but same happens.

Comment: What does your code look like? Why do you have 20k static strings in the first place? That seems like a very odd thing to do.

Comment: Do you really need the strings in code? Would reading them from a file work?

Comment: If not a separate file...at least a resource

Comment: What is the '...allowed limit...'? Is it a character count limit or size in MB limit?

Answer (score 13):

Just want to bring my recent experience to the table.

There is not much information around if you search the net for CS8103 error. And most information is not entirely precise.

We ran into this yesterday, in a large C# solution.

As I understand this compile error, the problem is the total length of all compile time defined strings concatenated.

I interprets this as the compiler puts all strings in a massive datablock, and then when a given string is referenced, it indexes into this (or similar).

So try to understand it as all your strings defined in cs files - concatenated to one. If this string becomes too large - we risk runtime errors as the Roslyn issue above explains.

All strings in code, all that is inside double quotes count.

```
public void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    string test = "AnotherTest" + " " + "run";
}
```

A program like above has 4 + 11 + 1+ 3 = 19 => "testAnotherTest run"

Our assembly reached the limit yesterday when merging a feature branch into master. That was the famous drop that makes the cup run over.

There seems to be no workaround, but to split your large assembly into smaller pieces, or move large block of strings into resources or other external files.

We verified this by commenting out a large portion of legacy code - and we could compile again.

Our solution was to refactor a specific area out of the large assembly, and create a new assembly for this.

I know, soo much text - but thought this deserved a thorough explanation, as it was quite hard to figure out what caused the problem.

And given the sparse information else where, this is not a common problem. But it stops the production line, and no one can compile until a solution is fixed.

Comment: Note that all string constants would include null terminators, and would be encoded in UTF16, so your length estimates are off.

Answer (score 3):

I guess its a new compiler in VS2015, which restricts too much use of string literals.

See EmitErrorTests line 329:
http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Emit.UnitTests/Emit/EmitErrorTests.cs

The solution is to not overflow your heap. Try to get the total memory your program (if its already using too much) by

```
long totalHeapMemoryUsed  = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
```

Try to not use static strings, but limit it to local scopes (function or class scope), or use Resources.

Answer (score 2):

Try to move long strings into Resources

In my case I had huge migration SQL scripts. This issue was resolved after I moved them into Resources

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem because we are using entity framework code first migration.

We use these migrations to run SQL scripts to update the database. These scripts can be large sometimes.

Over time the files accumulate and eventually, we got this error. Hiding the old sql scripts from the project essentially fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by adding the following (*ed lines) in the .csproj file:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    *<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    *<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <UserSecretsId>165df0cf-51ff-4f1e-b880-d98a9de58bc2</UserSecretsId>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Btw, my project is a .net core app with support for MVC - Razor

Comment: So your project has a large amount of string literals from compiled razor views? Compiling them at runtime seems like a poor solution.

Comment: Your answer seems to be a duplicate for this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62356355/asp-core-3-1-combined-length-of-user-strings-used-by-the-program-exceeds-allowed

Comment: My project has around 240 views which are static and called by a controller based on a url parameter. The views reside in the Home folder. But for some reason, it wouldn't compile without the above lines in the csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

I run in that error on a (more or less) small project.
To fake data, we saved some GQL Responses as Base64 in a helper class and provide them as const string.
I automated the code generation and wrote a partial class with these data.
the size of the whole class (just the autogenerated partial class) is a bit more than 10mb. This problem faced up when the file size jumped from 5mb to 10mb

I rewrote the code generation and write the base64 values and so on in a resx file.
Which solves this error.

To solve this in a .net standard, I have to install a NuGet package
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ResXResourceReader.NetStandard

Which provides the functionality of the System.Resources.Winform ResXResourceWriter

```
    using (var resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@"Resources.resx"))
    {
        foreach (var s in source)
        {
            resx.AddResource(s.Key, s.Base64Content);
        }
        resx.Generate();
    }
```