# Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string literals

Tags: c#

I am using c#.
I need to store 10mb data(base64 coded) in string/string builder and send it to sql server db.
I tried different ways but getting 'Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string literals." error.
tried below.. getting error

```
string str1="very large text...";
string str2="very large text..";
string tr3 = str1+str2;
```

please advise me how to achieve this?
Basically i want to send that string(base64) to api, and i don't want to store that file somewhere and read it.

Comment: Are you seriously want to store `10mb` string is represented by `literals` directly in the code? Do you can save it to some file and then read it?

Comment: Is the source file being generated?  With some code-gen tool?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear that what you want isn't possible. You should consider using "Resources" that you can embed into the assembly (they are basically files that are packaged into the same DLL as the code at build time).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193372/c-sharp-combined-length-of-user-strings-used-by-the-program-exceeds-allowed-limi)

Comment: i want to send that string (basically that is base64 ) to api, and we don't want to save that file in somewhere.I want to send like  a string.Any advise?