# BC37255: Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string or XML literals

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I got this error when compiling a Vb.Net project on VS 2019 version 16.11.21.

BC37255: Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string or XML literals

Any ideas ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50522293/9365244

Comment: Interesting topic to warn about executable size. Looks like a compiler bug JayV

Answer (score 0):

If you have large strings in your code, put them separately in a resource file.